# Trying to pass an array as an argument getting a double[4] to double conversion error

Tags: c++, arrays, double

The program is supposed to use functions to get input about each of the four regions sales figures then determine the highest and display both. Everything compiled fine until I wrote the last function FindHighest. I am trying to pass the sales array which is the data I collected from GetSales to FindHighest and determine the largest number of the array and cout that info.

The error I get when compiling is 
Error   1   error C2664: 'FindHighest' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'double [4]' to 'double'   g:\cis5\week6\week6\problem3.cpp    31  1   Week6

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

double GetSales(string);
void FindHighest(double);
void Validate(double&, string);

const int NUMBER_OF_REGIONS = 4;
const string REGION[NUMBER_OF_REGIONS] = {"Northeast", "Southeast", "Northwest", "Southwest"};

int main(){ 
    double sales[NUMBER_OF_REGIONS] = {0.0};

    //This loop calls the function GetSales as it proceeds forward through the REGION array
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        sales[i] = GetSales(REGION[i]);
    }

    FindHighest(sales);

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}


//This function receives the region as a string and gathers the sales figure as input. It also calls the function Validate to vaildate that the sales figure is over $0.0
double GetSales(string region){
    double sales = 0.0;

    cout << "\nWhat is the total sales for " << region << " division: ";
    cin >> sales;
    Validate(sales, region);

    return sales;
}

//This function receives the sales figures as an array and determines which division had the highest sales and displays the name and amount
void FindHighest(double sales[]){
    string region = "";
    double highestSales = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_REGIONS; i++){
        if (sales[i] > highestSales){
            highestSales = sales[i];
            region = REGION[i];
        }
    }

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "The " << region << " division had the highest sales with a total of $" << highestSales;
}

//This function validates the sales input from the GetSales function
void Validate(double &sales, string region){
    while (sales < 0){
        cout << "I am sorry but this cannot be a negative number." << endl;
        cout << "Please enter a positive sales figure for " << region << " division: ";
        cin >> sales;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You problem is up at the top where you declare
`void FindHighest(double);`

That doesn't agree with the definition of FindHighest.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to mention that the parameter is an array in the function declaration

```
void FindHighest(double);
```

try making that

```
void FindHighest(double[]);
```

Comment: Be aware that `void FindHighest(double[]);` really means `void FindHighest(double*);`.  Though your question is about C++, section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) is excellent.